# I am compiling my program in ubuntu g++ correctly but it cant find my files?

Tags: g++

[Here is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBYDH.png)

I created a c++ program with two .cpp's and one .h. I downloaded and installed both ubuntu and g++ and both are working. However when I save my work in visual studio and enter it in ubuntu as in the image, it says the file doesnt exist... but it does!

I've looked everywhere on the internet, watched youtube videos, asked classmates, I cannot seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: You're running Visual Studio on Ubuntu? Or do you mean Visual Studio Code? What happens when you list (`ls`) the files in that directory?

Comment: Also, do not post images of code/errors. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)